# Azure resource Locks - how they work

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

from new Azure Portal, I selected a Virtual machine and then I am able to create Multilple resource locks of type - Delete.

How does these Multiple resource locks of same type works/helps , when all of these lock does the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

As an administrator, you may need to lock a subscription, resource group, or resource to prevent other users in your organization from accidentally deleting or modifying critical resources. You can set the lock level to CanNotDelete or ReadOnly.

CanNotDelete means authorized users can still read and modify a resource, but they can't delete the resource. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources).

> How does these Multiple resource locks of same type works/helps , when
>   all of these lock does the same thing ?

You could create VMs in the same group and lock the resource group.